# Checking for Linux capabilities to set thread priority

Tags: c++, docker, pthreads, linux-capabilities

I have a C++ application that uses `pthread_setschedparam()` to set thread priority. Inside a docker container this fails with EPERM.

How can I detect if my process has the necessary capabilities to set thread priority ?

Comment: Possibly related: [CoreOS - pthread_create priority thread returns EPERM when run as root](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/410).

Comment: @jwerich: Looks like the same issue, but no code example how to check whether a process has the capability or not.

Comment: Right. I suppose your container is running on top of CoreOS. Isn't it? It looks like a bug in CoreOS.

Comment: As for the checking, I believe you can include `sys/capability.h` (from libcap) and call [cap_get_proc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_get_proc) and [cap_get_flag](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_get_flag).

Answer (score 3):

I guess your C++ application can able to set the thread priority because on host it has the required linux capability `cap_sys_nice`

All the linux capabilities on host can be figured out using this command `capsh --print`

Here inside docker conatiner you need to set this capability using `--cap-add` option.

`docker run -it --rm --cap-add SYS_NICE ubuntu bash`

If it didn't worked try this

`docker run -it --rm --userns host --cap-add SYS_NICE ubuntu bash`

Since there might be some issue without `--userns` option as mentioned here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25622

Worst case: If any of this didn't works then try to run container with `--privileged` option, this will add all the linux capabilities to this container, though it is not recommended.

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my intent is really the opposite. I would like to tune down my app instead of giving the container more capabilities.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice! I know the OP is looking to do the opposite, but I ended up here via google because I needed to do this instead. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to check is simply to try it and see if you get the `EPERM` error.  For one thing, LSMs can set arbitrary rules on the allowable scheduler changes.

So the right thing to do is probably just to log a warning (once!) when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the man of `pthread_setschedparam()` it states:

> For a description of the permissions required to, and the effect of,
>        changing a thread's scheduling policy and priority, and details of
>        the permitted ranges for priorities in each scheduling policy, see
>        sched(7).

In the man of sched it state among other things:

> A thread must be privileged (CAP_SYS_NICE) in order to set or modify
>          a SCHED_DEADLINE policy

For more information you can look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Comment: How do I check if my process has CAP_SYS_NICE ?